# How to generate report from huge mongodb document

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports

I am new in jasper report . I try to generate report using jasper report with mongodb from 2 lack documents by calling Java API . If just apply only find query is work well but I apply sorting. That time I got below exception .So how I resolve this problem  Anyone can help me.

com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 17144 and error message 'Executor error: OperationFailed: Sort operat
    ion used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.'

I construct following query,

```
<queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
                    "collectionName": "Customer_Detail",
                    "findQuery": $P!{whereClause}, 
                     sort:{'creditRating' : 1} 
                }, allowDiskUse: true]]>
    </queryString>
```

This is total exception

```
2017-05-27 10:10:33,647 INFO  [MongoDbQueryWrapper] - Processing mongoDB query
2017-05-27 10:10:33,666 DEBUG [MongoDbQueryWrapper] - 
Query: {
    "collectionName": "Customer_Detail",
    "findQuery": {},
     sort:{'creditRating' : 1}
    }, allowDiskUse: true
2017-05-27 10:10:33,674 INFO  [MongoDbDataSource] - New MongoDB Data Source
2017-05-27 10:10:42,062 DEBUG [JasparReportEngine] - ~SERVER03~-8068453390450533331~admin~~CustomerReportService~1~~~~~admin~~~~~17
~JasparReport Error
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 17144 and error message 'Executor error: OperationFailed: Sort operat
ion used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.' on server 192.168.1.105:27017
        at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getQueryFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:91)
        at com.mongodb.connection.QueryProtocol.receiveMessage(QueryProtocol.java:288)
        at com.mongodb.connection.QueryProtocol.execute(QueryProtocol.java:229)
        at com.mongodb.connection.QueryProtocol.execute(QueryProtocol.java:38)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:155)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:219)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.query(DefaultServerConnection.java:166)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:397)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:394)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:195)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:168)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:394)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:57)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:736)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:723)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:815)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:149)
        at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.MongoDbDataSource.next(MongoDbDataSource.java:139)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.advanceDataSource(JRFillDataset.java:1405)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1254)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1233)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1577)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:152)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:464)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:861)
        at mavens.dais.report.engine.JasparReportEngine.executeReport(JasparReportEngine.java:71)
        at mavens.dais.report.engine.DaisReportEngine.executeReport(DaisReportEngine.java:44)
        at mavens.dais.report.service.GenericReportService.executeService(GenericReportService.java:74)
        at mavens.dais.sep.service.delegator.ReportServiceDelegator.executeService(ReportServiceDelegator.java:13)
        at mavens.framework.service.helper.ServiceHelper.executeService(ServiceHelper.java:76)
        at mavens.framework.service.helper.ServiceHelper.executeService(ServiceHelper.java:53)
        at mavens.dais.sep.service.manager.ServiceManager.executeService(ServiceManager.java:131)
        at mavens.dais.sep.channel.manager.ChannelManager.processRequest(ChannelManager.java:74)
        at mavens.dais.sep.channel.gateway.DaisWebServiceGateway.process(DaisWebServiceGateway.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(Abstrac
tResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java
:75)
```

Comment: How have you created JRXML ? If you have created JRXML using jasper studio then you can sort by using Dataset and Query Dialog. Click on dataset where you have written query. Then you can check at the bottom there is sorting tab. Try to apply sort their.

Comment: Hi Anjum , sorting working well . but cant  get proper response from mongodb. that response time i got that error. so anything i  missing to configure in jrxml.